# How to test React component with children using jest and enzyme?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-redux, jestjs, enzyme-to-snapshot

Component to be tested. this.props.children have child components of example.js

```
class Example extends component {
  constructor(){
      super(props);
      this.state={};
    }
   render() {
        <div>{this.props.children}</div>
     }
}
```

test case

```
it("should render  Example with children", () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Example {...props} />);
     expect(wrapper.find("div").text()).toBe(""); //
   });
```

how to test the child components passed ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use like below

```
describe('Parent Component', () => {
   it('renders Child component', () => {
   const wrapper = shallow(<Parent store={store} />);
   expect(wrapper.find(Child).length).toEqual(1);
  });
});
```

Also if you want to test only child component div
use like this

```
const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent />);
expect(wrapper.find('Foo')).to.have.lengthOf(1);
```

Comment: what should be the values passed to store?it showing child undefind

Comment: that is only for your reference, you can pass props if you have that in you child otherwise without props is also fine